# MS special characters encoding on Linux Java

Tags: java, encoding

I'm having issues figuring out how to fix encoding. For example the following string with what I think has Microsoft special characters

```
¼ cup diced celery ©
```

prints out

```
Â¼ cup diced celery Â©
```

when I set encoding in Java OPT to

```
-Dfile.encoding=cp1252
```

or to

```
-Dfile.encoding=ISO-8859-1
```

If I remove -Dfile.encoding all together, I get

```
?? cup diced celery ??
```

The server is on Linux with UTF-8 encoding otherwise. I hope someone with some exposure to encoding can help me see the light.
Thanks a lot.

Comment: How do you display it?

Comment: @ jaroslawj: I display it in gsp, like this <li><% ingrediens[i] %></li>

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix the encoding by adding

```
response.setContentType("text/html; charset=cp1252");
```

into the page.